# Method that takes parameter and asks for month?

Tags: java

> Write a method that takes a parameter for the number of a month and prints the month's name. You may assume that the actual parameter value passed to the method is always between 1 and 12 inclusive.
>
> This method must be called monthName() and it must have an integer parameter.
>
> Calling monthName(8) should print August to the screen.
>
> You can call your method in the program's main method so you can test whether it works, but you must remove or comment out the main method before checking your code for a score.

I've been having a lot of trouble with this however I keep getting two errors- would anyone mind reading through my code and giving me corrections?

```
Errors: /tmp/sub-049616211/U5_L2_Activity_One.java:16: error: illegal initializer for String
{"January","February","March","April","May",
^

/tmp/sub-049616211/U5_L2_Activity_One.java:21: error: array required, but String found
System.out.println(months[month]);
```

```
public static void monthName(int month) {
    String months =
        { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    if (month <= 0 || month > 12) {
        System.out.println("That's not within the range 1 -12");
    } else {
        System.out.println(months[month]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number of Month:");

    int m = sc.nextInt();

    monthName(m);

    sc.close();
}

}
```

Comment: First of: Java and Javascript are different languages. This is a java question and has nothing to do with Javascript. And to your problem: You should read [The Java™ Tutorials - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and expecially the part **"Declaring a Variable to Refer to an Array"**

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in Java or in JavaScript? They are two different languages...

Comment: Sorry I accidentally clicked both- this is supposed to be in java

Answer (score 1):

On this line is your original error:

```
String months= {"January","February","March","April","May", "June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
```

The object you have is an array of Strings, yet you declare it as a String. Change

```
String months= ....
```

to:

```
String[] months= ...
```

to indicate that months is an array, not a single String.

A second issue you'll have, in Java, arrays are 0 based:

```
if(month <= 0 || month > 12) {
    System.out.println("That's not within the range 1 -12");
}else {
    System.out.println(months[month]);
}
```

Now, once you type 1, you'll want "January" to be printed, but it won't. The correct index for January is 0. So, change the above to:

```
if(month <= 0 || month > 12) {
    System.out.println("That's not within the range 1 -12");
}else {
    System.out.println(months[month-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Errors: /tmp/sub-049616211/U5_L2_Activity_One.java:16: error: illegal
> initializer for String {"January","February","March","April","May", ^
>
> /tmp/sub-049616211/U5_L2_Activity_One.java:21: error: array required,
> but String found System.out.println(months[month]);

Both error messages tell you, that you declared months as String, not String[].

Also consider to use the [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) class.